# Passing arguments to Docker containers via Kubernetes Deployment YML

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

I'm using a CI/CD pipeline to deploy a Node.js app on my Kubernetes cluster. Now, we use different sensible environment variables in local, and we would like to deploy them as environment variables within the cluster to be used by the different containers...

Which strategy should I go with?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

There are many tools created in order to let you inject secret into kubernetes safely.

Natively you can use the "Secrets" object: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/
And mount the secret as env var.

Alternatively, you can use some open source tools that make this process more secured by encrypting the secrets, here are some I recommend:
https://learnk8s.io/kubernetes-secrets-in-git
https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/platform/k8s

Comment: I was more thinking about this : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/
But was wondering whether the values could be injected in the CLI? To make it dynamic?

Comment: Use helm or kustomize is best practise. You can also use sed to make it "dynamic". This behavior is wrong though. If they are not secrets you can use configmap and create the configmap via CLI.